# Increase font size on PS4 for No Man's Sky

Tags: ps4, no-mans-sky

Is there a way to increase the font-size? My TV is 32" my eyes aren't the best, so I have to sit really close to actually read most of the menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this myself but the PS4 comes with a built-in accessibility system explained here: http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/accessibility.html

You can freely zoom in and enlarge what I hope is all text a game displays.

Comment: "Large Text" in the PS4 accessibility options does not affect in-game text. For example: http://www.itworld.com/article/2924324/personal-technology/i-needed-the-playstation-4s-accessibility-options-to-play-the-witcher-iii-and-they-didnt-work.html

Comment: The zoom function should work in any game, however: http://www.unstoppablegamer.com/ps4-accessibility-the-hands-on-experience/